"ObjectHandle is Invalid" when trying to get the root's children for one of multiple drives
I am using the OneDrive API in PHP and I retrieve the following list of drives for a user using /me/drives:
(
  [0] => Microsoft\Graph\Model\Drive Object
    (
      [_propDict:protected] => Array
        (
          [createdDateTime] => 2024-04-16T17:51:30Z
          [description] => Desc1
          [id] => b!ZdXcWExgQkiKkeYEMuOZof1MA3U_rxRJsnbh9pDQY80Lv8orpc9-RLQ0Lo7FaHPN
          [lastModifiedDateTime] => 2024-04-16T17:51:30Z
          [name] => OneDrive
          [webUrl] => https://my.microsoftpersonalcontent.com/personal/???/???
          [driveType] => personal
          [createdBy] => Array
            (
              [user] => Array
                (
                  [displayName] => SharePoint App
                )
            )
          [owner] => Array
            (
              [user] => Array
                (
                  [email] => ???
                  [displayName] => ???
                )
            )
          [quota] => Array
            (
              [deleted] => 0
              [remaining] => 943174818201
              [state] => normal
              [total] => 1104880336896
              [used] => 161705518695
              [storagePlanInformation] => Array
                (
                  [upgradeAvailable] => 
                )
            )
        )
    )
  [1] => Microsoft\Graph\Model\Drive Object
    (
      [_propDict:protected] => Array
        (
          [createdDateTime] => 2024-04-16T17:51:28Z
          [description] => 
          [id] => 740141a789bd6c6a
          [lastModifiedDateTime] => 2024-04-22T22:56:29Z
          [name] => OneDrive
          [webUrl] => https://my.microsoftpersonalcontent.com/personal/???/Documents
          [driveType] => personal
          [createdBy] => Array
            (
              [user] => Array
                (
                  [displayName] => SharePoint App
                )
            )
          [lastModifiedBy] => Array
            (
              [user] => Array
                (
                  [displayName] => System Account
                )
            )
          [owner] => Array
            (
              [user] => Array
                (
                  [email] => ???
                  [displayName] => ???
                )
            )
          [quota] => Array
            (
              [deleted] => 0
              [remaining] => 943174818201
              [state] => normal
              [total] => 1104880336896
              [used] => 161705518695
              [storagePlanInformation] => Array
                (
                  [upgradeAvailable] => 
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

Both drives are personal.
I select one of them (let's say the first) and try to list the contents:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/b!ZdXcWExgQkiKkeYEMuOZof1MA3U_rxRJsnbh9pDQY80Lv8orpc9-RLQ0Lo7FaHPN/items/root/children?$top=999

However I get:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "ObjectHandle is Invalid",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-04-23T09:48:26",
            "request-id": "7da7ea84-88ba-4bc9-a9fd-4a547eca49f1",
            "client-request-id": "7da7ea84-88ba-4bc9-a9fd-4a547eca49f1"
        }
    }
}

This seems to work when the user only has one drive.
I also trying URL encoding the drive ID but it doesn't make any difference.
Is there a problem with how I'm defining the root folder?

I'm facing the same issue any luck with the fix

I found a different workaround, which was to use me/drive . This appears to be the canonical drive for a user, and I could ignore the multiple drives.
